# SQLalchemy slow with Redshift

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a 44k rows table in a pandas Data Frame. When I try to export this table (or any other table) to a Redshift database, the process takes ages. I'm using sqlalchemy to create a conexion like this:

```
import sqlalchemy as sal
engine = sal.create_engine('redshift+psycopg2://blablamyhost/myschema')
```

The method I use to export the tables is Pandas `to_sql` like this:

```
dat.to_sql(name="olap_comercial",con=eng,schema="monetization",index=False,if_exists="replace" ,dtype={"description":sal.types.String(length=271),"date_postoffer":sal.types.DATE})
```

Is it normal that it is so slow? I'm talking about more than 15 minutes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is normal to be that slow (and possibly slower for large clusters). Regular sql inserts (as generated by sqlalchemy) are very slow for Redshift, and should be avoided.

You should consider using S3 as an intermediate staging layer, your data flow will be:
dataframe->S3->redshift

Ideally, you should also gzip your data before uploading to S3, this will improve your performance as well.

This can be coordinated from your python script using BOTO3 and psycopg2 
https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: I wrote a wrapper around boto3 and psycopg2 to solve this exact problem: https://github.com/agawronski/pandas_redshift